# What are the requirements a computer function must meet to be considered "monotonic"?

Tags: prolog, logic, logical-purity

**What are the requirements a computer function/procedure/predicate must meet to be considerd "monotonic"?**

```
Let A be some thing ,
Let B be some thing ,
Let R be a monotonic relationship between A and B ,
Let R_ be a non-monotonic relationship between A and B ,
Let R become false if R_ is true ,
Let R_ become true if R is false ,
Let C be a constraint in consideration of R ,
Let C become false if R_ is true ,
Let D be the collection of constraints C (upon relationship R) .

**What is D ?**
```

I have reviewed some literature, e.g. a Wikipedia article "[monotonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)".
I am most interested in a practical set of criteria I can apply when
pragmatically involved with computer programming. 
What are some tips and best practices I should follow when creating and designing my functions, such that they are more likely to be "monotonic"?

Comment: funny , I had "haskell" as a tag but it got removed , perhaps such a consideration as this is of no interest to a Haskell programmer ?

Comment: perhaps this question would be a better fit on http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: What is the context here? Where do all of those "let"s come from? "Monotonic" and "non-monotonic" don't really make sense unless you have an ordering on the items in/of type `A` and in `B`. So, at the very least, this question cannot be answered in a specific way without that information. Also, unless I'm mistaken, it sounds like you think monotonic functions are "better" than non-monotonic functions which is not true. It is just a certain mathematical property that some functions have (and some don't).

Comment: Oh, this sounds like it might be very logic programming specific, since this is tagged "prolog." Incidentally, that would be a good reason for the `haskell` tag to have been removed if that is the case... I don't know much about logic programming, but I can imagine there is probably a specific kind of monotonicity that is important there (unless I'm totally missing the mark on what you're asking).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **logic programming**, and also in *logic*, the classification "monotonic" almost invariably refers to [**monotonicity of entailment**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonicity_of_entailment).

This fundamental property is encountered for example in classical first-order logic: When you are able to derive a consequence from a set of clauses, then you can *also* derive the consequence when you *extend* the set of clauses. Conversely, *removing* a clause does not entail consequences that were previously *not* the case.

In the **pure** subset of Prolog, this property *also* holds, from a declarative perspective. We therefore sometimes call it the pure *monotonic* subset of Prolog, since impurities do not completely coincide with constructs that *destroy* monotonicity.

Monotonicity of entailment is the basis and sometimes even necessary condition for several approaches that reason over logic programs, notably **declarative debugging**.

Note that Prolog has several language constructs that may *prevent* such reasoning in general. Consider for example the following Prolog program:

```
f(a).
f(b).
f(c).
```

And the following query:

```
?- setof(., f(X), [_,_]).
false.
```

Now I *remove* one of the facts from the program, which I indicate by <s>strikethrough</s> text:

```
f(a) :- false.
f(b).
f(c).
```

If Prolog programs were monotonic, then every query that *previously* failed would definitely now fail *all the more*, since I have *removed* something that was previously the case.

However, we now have:

```
?- setof(X, f(X), [_,_]).
true.
```

So, `setof/3` is an example of a predicate that *violates* monotonicity!

Comment: A very excellent answer ! Thank-you very much , @mat . Unfortunately the "accept this answer" checkmark button is dysfunctionl , dkw . I question the use of `setof` in such a manner to prove your point .  Yer exmpl is equivalent to ``` (setof(__X__,f(__X__),__Y__)) , __Y__ = [_,_] .``` , I believe it is the `=` thus not the `setof` that causes the violation of monotonicity .

Comment: In the example above , are "a" , "b" , "c" the names of other functions ?  They are barewords so I assume they are keywords or function names ?

Comment: Sorry , formatting problem in my comment above , it seems hard to use `_` underscore in stackoverflow comments .  s/b :  :- ((setof(X,f(X),Y)) , Y = [`_`,`_`])

Comment: @Kintalken: if you have formatting problems in comments, write the comment a 2nd time, then delete the preceding malformed one.

Comment: The very same `setof/3` does not violate monotonicity as long as one only uses partial lists with anonymous variables, like `setof(X, f(X), [_,_|_])`

Comment: @mat I added a follow-up question to the main topic as-if it was another "answer" .

Comment: ... the follow-up question was subsequently deleted by "brad" .  Not sure how to facilate discussion on stackoverflow .  Seem's to be oriented as some kind of american-style service industry . In exchange for revealing to the world that you are stupid , a servant will answer your question for you . In return , the servant must demonstrate they are a master , by providing the answer , and is benefited the tremendous feeling they gain by being an expert in a world , and the receipt of some shiny stackoverflow gold stars . Absolutely forbidden : the "tangential" .i.e. "off-topic"  .

Comment: follow-up question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901559/is-this-pogram-entailedmonotonically/44100451#44100451